# How to mock an array containing objects using mockito?

Tags: arrays, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

In my Mockito unit test I am trying to mock an array containing instances of the object `Message`. To do this I try to mock it like normal objects so like:

`private var messagesMock = mock(Array<Message>::class.java)`

This gives the following error/exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class [Lrobot.fsrt.robotguest.common.data.Message;
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - VM does not not support modification of given type
```

How to mock an array the right way using Mockito?

Comment: Also note: your question isn't really clear. Is `Message` a variable, or is it a generic type. Do you want to have ONE array with the object Message within it, or do you want to create some generic `Array<Message>` instance? So a real [mcve] with additional context would definitely help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A distinct non-answer: you (almost) **never** mock objects that represent containers!

An array is just that: a container.

You create the container with the size you need, and then you put your mocked objects **into** that ordinary container, and make sure that container with your prepared content gets used by your production code.

It is as simple as that: you don't mock arrays, or lists, or maps: you create them as is, and manipulate their *content*!

Comment: What if I want to test the iterator?

Comment: What do you mean? Testing your own implementation of some interface like iterable is a different story.